# Just a Regular Word Search

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, word-search

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #36: Twisted Classics 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6372)</sup>

---

Here's a regular word search. Find three twisty things.

```
[ a - z ] ? b ( f \ ( ) . ( - l * 3 * ] 
| | ( * * - ) a . { 9 } . ( ) d e * + z 
\ \ w f ] f a u l * | e 5 . . f t s | - 
w # ) ) s - z ] 4 2 [ . . { | | e s * a 
] ( r e ) { ) - y e - d | . . 3 + s - [ 
) 1 . - 2 | p * ] [ ) 3 e | ) * [ p ] - 
- 1 \ } \ . ) ) \ ? a u | ] ( l s { ) } 
( . l 2 ( ] . t j ) ( - + | { ? * a 1 n 
( . z ) t . | } ? 0 [ + z ? - 2 ] ) l 0 
* \ / - . ( 4 3 ( ) * z / ] ) ( } \ ) . 
) = c ( ] { + + s - * w [ \ * l | - + { 
. [ ) l . k - z * + t ( ( ) | / r . [ 7 
( { ? s } v * i ) w u 5 ? e 8 ) ) } . } 
u q * ( . o ) . ) ] ) ( + # ? u | . 1 { 
\ ( | p ( a 3 ) \ w ) . i ? | / s 1 3 - 
) . - . - ? c ) w ( ) * { t 3 } { 3 a v 
| | ( ( ) ) o . + - | . ( ? z w * + ? . 
e { { } } + . t - ? ( - * w \ - x * \ w 
} . 3 [ ] { 1 1 } | a a [ ] ] \ - p ? * 
. o } . ) - ? 8 m t o w u . . ( ) * [ -

Words:

twisted
classics
fortnightly
topic
challenge
puzzling
stack
exchange
```

Hint 1:

> The three twisted things may *correspond* to three colors.

Hint 2:

> Try focusing on *regions*.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but it seems like your "regular word search" is corrupted. ;)

Comment: @micsthepick Looks like a regular word search to me :)

Comment: Well, I (in a suitably extended sense of "I") can find all the words, but in trivial boring ways. I can find some of them in more interesting ways, but not all. (In particular, I can't find "puzzling" in a nontrivial way.) And so far I'm at a loss to guess what the three twisty things might be...

Comment: Well, I might have found "puzzling", if things can be found backwards. Haven't managed anything else, yet...

Comment: Really, Riley? You posted this 46 seconds after FTC #36 officially began! Did the first person at the table get to eat all the food at your house growing up? :)

Comment: Ignoring the trivial versions I found "puzzling", "classics", "stack" (twice) and one almost trivial that matches "twisted" or "topic".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The three twisty things are:

> plot, Oliver, and puzzles.

These can be found in the pattern from David Starkeys answer as follows:

> For each of the colours in the puzzling SE logo, we take the letters in the corresponding parts of the grid as follows:
>  [image]
>  For the letters in the red part anagram to "plot", the letters in the yellow part anagram to "oliver", and the letters in the green part anagram to "puzzles".

These things are indeed twisty, as

> we can combine "plot" and "Oliver" with twist to get "plot twist" and "Oliver twist". Puzzles are of course also twisty, especially during this Fortnightly Topic Challenge!

Comment: Yes, you got it!

Comment: Hey, Reinier! Thank you so much for following! Would you please upvote 5 example questions for the site so that we can get through to the Commitment phase? Cheers!

Comment: We need at least 40 questions with a score of at least 10 :)

Answer (score 30):

This regular word search requires

> [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

The simplest solution would be

> `.*` which matches any length of any characters and occurs a number of places in the puzzle

Here's an example of such a solution

> [image: .*]

But, that's no fun and seems a bit like cheating.  So, let's restrict it by requiring it to only match one of the words we're looking for.

> [image: WIP]

Honorable mentions (matching multiple):

> (t|u).+
>  t.+
>  \u(.)*
>  (q|.)+
>  [a-z]*
>  (.)*

While a couple words have yet to be found in a unique way, @Sleafar pointed out a particular [pattern](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/puzzling/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=a7ebbe6c6b60) that can be made by including the ones that match multiples:

> [image: logo]

Which would make the "three twisty things"

> <strike>The 3 colors being twisted around each other</strike>
>  WIP Thoughts:
>  - The logo goes from left edge to right edge, but there's an extra row on top and 2 rows on bottom, perhaps there's something in there I missed.
>  - Perhaps there is some kind of jagged path (like A1->B2->A3->B4...)
>  - Maybe it involves wrapping around, so left edge meets right and top meets bottom

Comment: Open for suggestions for *topic* and *exchange*.  I've been looking for one using the group capture syntax of `\#` but I'm not seeing any.

Comment: Once you see the [pattern](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/puzzling/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=a7ebbe6c6b60), it's almost too easy. There's another "fortnightly" in the bottom right corner -> "\w[11}".

Comment: @Sleafar I knew the `{11}` had to make fortnightly somehow.  I never went past the w for some reason.

Comment: I ignored everything without a letter as "too trivial", but with your definition (matches only one word) it makes sense. But "(t|u).+." matches 2 words although it fits the pattern.

Comment: @Sleafar I think even that might be too restrictive.  Using the pattern you noticed, I found a couple more that match multiples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79050/discussion-between-sleafar-and-david-starkey).

Comment: As it stands, this is merely a partial answer. You have yet to identify the three twisty things.

Comment: @Riley Yes. I mentioned it in the chat discussion, but forgot to add it in here.

Comment: Those are not the three twisty things. They should be twisty on their own, not twisted together.

Comment: I've added a hint. Hopefully that will help.

Comment: Huh. I looked explicitly for things that matched exactly one of the words, and didn't find any for "puzzling". I wonder where my bug was. ... Ah, found it: handled half the diagonals wrong. Oh well :-).

Comment: I've added a bounty to this question. Try not to overthink it and focus on the hint :)

Comment: I have added a second hint.